# optimalizacja using fmin_powell, only positive parameters

Tags: python, scipy

I've been trying optimize coefficients using the fmin_powell method.
I want an optimizer to check only positive values. Therefore I added the condition whether any of parameters is negative - return 100000000.0

```
coeff = np.array([1.,1.,1.,1.])

def run(coeff, *func):
     if (coeff[0] or coeff[1] or coeff[2] or coeff[3]) < 0: return 100000000.0
     else:
          [some math operations]
          return Energy

def optimize(f):
   return opt.fmin_powell(run, coeff, args=(f,f), disp=0)

f = ['1a','2b','3c', '4d', '5e', '6e', '7f', '8g']

p = Pool(processes=8)
async_ret = p.map(optimize,f,chunksize=1)
result = async_ret.get()
p.terminate()
```

Anyways that I wrote down a condition, I am getting negative values:

```
    [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]10.1985596621
    [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]10.1985596621
    [ 2.  1.  1.  1.]10.2100842541
    [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]10.1985596621
    [ 0.38196603  1.          1.          1.        ]10.1822540716
    [ 0.14589804  1.          1.          1.        ]10.1678012695
    [ 0.0557281  1.         1.         1.       ]10.1563797355
    [ 0.02128625  1.          1.          1.        ]10.1480644959
    [ 0.01000002  1.          1.          1.        ]10.1433906566
    [  1.55472633e-08  -6.18034000e-01   1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]10.1319877158
    [  1.55472633e-08  -3.23606803e+00   1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]10.1319475286
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While on the surface it seems like a good idea to restrict the search space by setting the cost function to a high value, this approach has a few drawbacks.

1. You need to be sure that this value dominates the cost function.
2. The optimizer does not *know* that the range is forbidden. It just sees a high cost but that does not prevent it to go there.
3. You are creating a plateau in the cost function. When the optimizer runs into the forbidden area it may not know how to get out because the function looks the same in every direction.

In general, it is better to use a bounded or constrained optimizer. That way the algorithm knows where it may not go. Usually I use [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) and let it choose automatically which optimization algorithm to use, based on the information (cost function, derivatives, bounds, constraints) it gets.

However, if you really need to use a specific optimization algorithm that does not take bounds or constraints you can help it get back into the feasible region by making the cost function slope towards positive values. For example:

```
if (coeff[0] or coeff[1] or coeff[2] or coeff[3]) < 0: 
    return (np.minimum(coef, 0)**2 + 1) * 100000000.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining!

Comment: I created a new topis as I am getting an error message: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). Maybe you know what is going on wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43152150/ambiguous-elements-while-optimizing-fmin-powell