# ambiguous elements while optimizing , fmin_powell

Tags: python, scipy

I've encountered a problem while optimizing parameters using the fmin_powell method.

```
coeff = np.array([1.,1.,1.,1.])

def run(coeff, *func):
     if np.any(coeff < 0): return (np.minimum(coeff, 0)**2 + 1) * 100000000.0
     else:
          [some math operations]
          return Energy

def optimize(f):
   return opt.fmin_powell(run, coeff, args=(f,f), disp=0)

f = ['1a','2b','3c', '4d', '5e', '6e', '7f', '8g']

p = Pool(processes=8)
async_ret = p.map(optimize,f,chunksize=1)
result = async_ret.get()
p.terminate()
```

Namely, I am getting the error message in return:

```
  async_ret = p.map(optimize,f,chunksize=1)
  File "/apps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/apps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I thought the problem was in the line: `if np.any(coeff < 0): return (np.minimum(coeff, 0)**2 + 1) * 100000000.0`, however, I do not notice a mistake.

Does anybody see where the issue might be?

Comment: on my side, this code works... I do not see your error. but async_ret.get() fails since the output of map is a list and lists do not have a get() method...

Comment: This error is produced when a boolean number array is used in a context that expects a scalar boolean value. An `if` statement is the most obvious. `and` expressions also have problem (Python `and` short circuits),  Your code may be producing the array in the wrong place, but the error appears in `multiprocessing`.  Dig there.